# How to remember previous numbers inputted in loop?

Tags: python

What I want to do, is to write a program that given a sequence of real numbers entered by the user, calculates the mean. Entering the sequence should be finished by inputting ’end’. To input more than 1 number I try:

```
num=input("Enter the number: ")
while num!="end":
    num = input("Enter the number: ")
```

But I don't want the program to "forget" the first 'num', because I'll need to use it later to calculate the mean. What should I write to input and then use more than one value, but not a specific number of values? User should can enter the values until they enter 'end'. All of values need to be use later to calculate the mean. Any tip for me?

Comment: You’ll want to make a `list` and `append` numbers to that list…

Comment: have a list and add the numbers to the list up until you get `end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define an empty list.

```
numbers = []
```

Then, ask for your input in an infinite loop. If the input is `"end"`, `break` out of the loop. If not, `append` the result of that `input()` to `numbers`. Remember to convert it to a `float` first!

```
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "end":
        break
    numbers.append(float(num))
```

Finally, calculate the mean:

```
mean = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
print("Mean: ", mean)
```

However, note that calculating the mean only requires that you know the sum of the numbers and the count. If you don't care about remembering all the numbers, you can just keep track of the sum.

```
total = 0
count = 0
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "end":
        break
    total += float(num)
    count += 1

print("Mean: ", total / count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mean is sum of all nos/total nos. Let's take input from user and add it to list, because we can easily use `sum()` function to find sum and `len()` function to find total nos. Your code:

```
obs=[]
while True:
    num=input("Enter number: ")
    if num=="end":
        break
    else:
        obs.append(int(num))
print("Mean: ",(sum(obs)/len(obs)))
```